The Missing Link
The Missing Link
What is the missing link?

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Accessible version (and for myself): There are 5 spaces on each link, each with 3 possible colours (Red, Yellow, Green). I will transcribe each link clockwise from the bottom-left, so the Puzzling logo would be YRGYG. I will transcribe the links from left to right. Middle (4, ?, 12): GYYGR, RGRGR, GYYGR, GYRGY, ? GYYRY, GYYGR, GYRRR, GGYRR, GGYGR, GYYGR, RYRRY, GGYRR, RYRRY, GGYRR, RYYRR, GGYGY. Top left (5, ?, 6): GYRRR, RYRGY, GGYRR, RYRRR, RYRRR, ?, GGRGR, GGYGY, GGYRY, GYRGR, RYRGY, GGRRR. Bottom left (5, ?, 4): GYYRY, RGRGR, GGYRY, GYYGR, RYRGY, ? GYYGR, GYRRY, GGRGR, GGYGY.

First observation:

 Using Benjamin Wang's transcription, the first color is always G or R, never Y. Doing this for all positions gives these possibilities:1 GR2 YG3 YR4 GR5 RY

This leads us towards

 Binary. Especially because following this rule, there are 32 (2^5) possible symbols, which is the lowest power of 2 which can hold all 26 letters of the alphabet. Given the observation above, a color cannot simply represent 1 or 0 all of the time, it depends on the position within the symbol.

Looking at the

 most significant bit, we would expect the binary to be a 0 around 70% of the time, not only because that is the case for 16/26 letters (62%), but also because of the frequencies of each letter in the english language.In the first position, G appears 26 times and R 10 times (72% | 28%), so G is likely to be 0 in the first position.

Continuing

 it is very unlikely for the second bit to be 1 if the first was 1, because 11000 is 24. Most of the symbols have RY rather than RG, so it's Y0G1 in the second position.11100 is impossible if we asssume we are working with the alphabet, and both symbols that start with RG continue with R, so R0Y1 in the third position.11010 (26) is probably also impossible because we are working with A0Z25 here, unless 0 is a space. But let's try it with the assumption that G0R1 in the fourth position.We use frequency analysis again for the least significant bit and expect a 1 40% of the time, so R0Y1.

Using all this, we can now decode everything

 Middle: eyeb?hecometotown
 Top left: cross?inpark
 Bottom left: hyper?edin

 The question mark can be replaced with "link" in each case. The left parts form eyeblink, crosslink and hyperlink. The right parts "Link, he come to town", Linkin Park, and LinkedIn.

Final observations:

 The two possible colors for each position are the ones not present in the original PSE logo. E.g. since the inner bottom left is yellow, it can only be G/R in the cipher.
 Looking at the 0/1 mappings we've found, we see that they form a "loop" of priority (which one is 1 in binary), like in the game rock papers scissors: R > G, G > Y, Y > R, the order of which is presumably determined by the natural reading order "Red, Green, Yellow"


Good solve Lukas! Nice to see that you were able to figure it out using frequency analysis. There is however a logical order of the colors that I used, in combination with how they are used in the original PSE logo.
